# Create / Edit node and continue editing on same page after submit

Tags: 8

D7 has module "Save & Edit".

There are any solutions for D8?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?

Answer (score 4):

The [Save & Edit module](https://www.drupal.org/project/save_edit) is a very basic module. It comprises of 6 total functions, so a port could be done less than a day.

Alternatively, if the your requirement is to just save editing progress while keeping the editor window up, the [Autosave form](https://www.drupal.org/project/autosave_form) module does that.

If you're looking to go the custom code route, some simple jQuery form manipulation can add a button which can trigger a form redirection & submit. For example:

```
// Set the form destination to the edit form and submit it.
jQuery('form.node-form').attr('action', '/node/<NID>/edit?destination=node/<NID>/edit'); 
jQuery('.node-form').submit();
```

Comment: For custom code route, a more Drupaly way would be to use hook_form_alter to add the new button and in the summit handler of your new button use [setRedirect](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AsetRedirect/8.2.x)